# IBM Worklight - How can I execute JavaScript code before updating the application?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore, worklight-runtime

When a new software update is available, if user has data stored in jsonstore I need to allow user to commit them to the server before applying the software update, so his/her uncommited updates don't get lost.
Currently user is unable to use the application until the update is installed.

Is there a way to execute JavaScript code before updating the application so I can initialize the jsonstore, take the data and send to the adapter before performing the update installation?

Comment: You might be able to in wlInitOptions file, before the WL.Client.init.  Have not tried it though

Comment: Nope, no proper hook is available.

Comment: Sorry I didn't add much details of the scenario.

Comment: The scenario I want to cover is: user logs into the app and start creating/updating records while he has no connectivity, thus we keep them in jsonstore. The next day, user login to the app again (now with connectivity) and receive the screen to update the app, but if he does so, and this update has some different searchFields for a given jsonstore collection he won't be able to initialize the collection after the update installation and thus won't be able to push the data from the jsonstore back to the server.

Comment: My answer below stands; there is no mechanism to allow this. You'll need to make your code more resilient to such changes in the collection.

Comment: @user2533254, BTW, how does the user login without server connectivity? it wouldn't be very secure to do the login locally...

Answer (score 0):

There is no programmatic hook available for a developer to use in order to perform an action prior to a Direct Update request.

That said, a Direct Update does not take place during runtime per-se, rather only:

1. Upon application initialization
2. Upon returning from the background to the foreground

So from what I understand, only the second scenario above is not being handled.
In the first scenario the user did not yet perform any data manipulations.

Not sure I completely understand the scenario, as you didn't elaborate much, but...
A possible solution would be to use the [Cordova Events API (pause, resume)](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause).

In theory, you could detect the case where the application was tasked with moving to the background and hopefully save the user data in a secondary collection before that.

And so, when the app is resumed but a Direct Update request has arrived and the primary collection was not previously saved/synced with the server (check with some flag, maybe?) then you could restore the app state using the secondary collection; essentially resume the app with the "unsaved" user data despite the Direct Update request. You/the user could then save and sync the data.

Or something like that.
Feel free to also [submit a feature request](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014907906&ps=25).

Answer (score 0):

We saw that the "unload" and "beforeunload" events are fired before a DirectUpdate. Maybe this is an option for code if the data is still available in memory at that point in time?

[WL 5.0.6.1 Android - Direct Update keeps Native/Cordova resources active/in memory (e.g. BusyIndicator) but reference is lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623000/wl-5-0-6-1-direct-update-keeps-native-cordova-resources-active-in-memory-e-g-b)