# WL 5.0.6.1 Android - Direct Update keeps Native/Cordova resources active/in memory (e.g. BusyIndicator) but reference is lost

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

We are having a problem when we have the following sequence:

- App Startup
- Web Resources start
- Show a Busy Indicator (1)
- Connect to WL Server
- Direct Update gets triggered
- Web Resources restart
- Show a Busy Indicator (2)
- Connect to WL Server
- Success
- Load and change to welcome page
- Hide Busy Indicator (2)

This has the effect that in the direct-updated web resources we are (of course) loosing/missing the reference to the busy indicator (1) and we are not able to hide that indicator after the direct update was triggered. So then, we have two indicators (1) (2) open and only one (2) is closed, the old one (1) is up forever.

One solution would be to get an event before the direct update is triggered/executed ... there we could hide our indicator (1). This would then become quite similar to this question: [IBM Worklight - How can I execute JavaScript code before updating the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020957/ibm-worklight-how-can-i-execute-javascript-code-before-updating-the-applicatio)

A more general approach would be to trigger a "deeper" restart of the app ... meaning to also restart the native shell and all cordova resources. Then all native resources like busy indicator and other things should be removed and reset, right?

Is there any way to achieve such a "deep" restart of the app after direct update? Is this problem known?

**UPDATE Sept. 5**

We saw that the following events are fired sometime before the DirectUpdate restarts the web resources:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload",
    function() { 
       WL.Logger.debug("busy test - unload2"); 
        app.busytest.hide();
            }
        , false);

window.addEventListener("unload",
    function() { 
       WL.Logger.debug("busy test - unload3"); 
         app.busytest.hide();
            }
        , false);
```

... but unfortunately hiding our WL.BusyIndicator "busytest" does not work in these events anymore. Does anyone have any ideas?

But maybe some other cleanup code could be placed there in case of a DirectUpdate?

Answer (score 1):

Busy indicator is a singleton. If you create several busy indicators, show them and then hide of them - all will be hidden.

Comment: you would think that this is the case.... but this is not the case. As mentioned above when "Showing" a busy indicator before the DirectUpdate, "Hiding" the busy indicator after the DirectUpdate does not work anymore - because you have to call `var busytest = new WL.BusyIndicator('content', {text : 'Loading...'});` at some point in the code and this get's executed again after the DirectUpdate. - not even in the "unload" and "beforeunload" events "Hiding" the old instance of the indicator does work anymore!

Comment: FYI ... we are currently seeing that in the Android Simulator with Nexus4 Android 4.3 API 18. On iPhone Simulator it seems to be OK and the busy seems to go away after DirectUpdate. We will look if we can test that on a device ... although this is not planned if an error already appears in the Simulator.

Comment: tested on Android phone LG Optimus with 4.1.2. The same problem exists ... BusyIndicator does not stop/hide when DirectUpdate is completed. After DirectUpdate, javascript reference to BusyIndicator is gone. Calling "hide" on a "new" indicator object (even several times extra) does not hide the one that is still visible/overlayed from before the DirectUpdate.

Comment: Try creating new busyIndicator and calling busy.show() first. Then call busy.hide(). Due to async nature of busyIndicator you might need to call busy.hide() inside of a setTimeout for 50-100ms.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your proposal .... what I do right now is 1. new BusyIndicator and show in wlCommonInit 2.client.connect 3. onSuccess and onFailure busy.hide.  ... now with DirectUpdate 1. and 2. is executed twice due to the restart of the web assets. 3. only once .... even if I put 5 or 6 busy.hide in the onFailure and onSuccess it does not hide the first Busy Indicator .... do you propose to put a setTimeout into the onSuccess and onFailure now? Will that really change something?